# syntax error, unexpected '=' in eval()'d code

Tags: php, eval

What is wrong with this code:

`<?php eval(" $start = microtime(true)*1000; echo 'hello'; $end=microtime(true)*1000; $time = $end-$start; $time = round($time,4); echo '<br />Time taken: '.$time.'ms<br />'; ");  ?>`

It's exactly one line code(dont ask why) but for readablility I repeat

```
<?php 
eval(" $start = microtime(true)*1000; 
    echo 'hello'; 
    $end=microtime(true)*1000; 
    $time = $end-$start; 
    $time = round($time,4); 
    echo '<br />Time taken: '.$time.'ms<br />';
");  
?>
```

I get this error: 
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in ...\test2.php(1) : eval()'d code on line 1`

Comment: Why on Earth are you doing it all in an `eval()` statement?

Comment: I have a reason, it's part of something bigger.

Comment: Remove the `eval()`, and it works fine: http://codepad.org/HlnP46j9

Comment: There isn't really any good reason for using eval() whether it's part of something bigger or not - there's always a better way than eval()

Comment: Than tell me how can I execute a string containing php code inside my php file?

Comment: @Dharman It being part of something bigger does not make it less unnerving.

Comment: Use single quotes around the outer string. and escape the inner quotes. You have a variable `$start` which PHP is interpolating in double quotes to a scalar, to which you cannot assign via `=`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When using double quotes, you have to escape every dollar sign, without it, php will try to resolve variables from your scope into the final string.

Since you probably don't have `$start` variable defined, it is treated as empty string and your code starts with '='.

Comment: I knew it was something simple. (facepalm). Question closed

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
eval(' $start = microtime(true)*1000; 
    echo \'hello\'; 
    $end=microtime(true)*1000; 
    $time = $end-$start; 
    $time = round($time,4); 
    echo \'<br />Time taken: \'.$time.\'ms<br />\';
');
```