# Can't understand syntax error, unexpected '=' in eval()'d code

Tags: php, eval

I've search different forms but didn't understand how to solve the problem first found here ([first link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384864/syntax-error-unexpected-in-evald-code), [second link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142550/unexpected-end-in-evald-code)) but its giving me the error in eval. I can't figure it out how to solve in that code in foreach loop.

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if(!strstr($key, 'removeFile')){
                //initialize variables using eval
                eval("$" . $key . " = '" . sanitize($value) . "';");
        }
}
```

Comment: `eval("\$" . $key . " = '" . sanitize($value) . "';");` It's **right there in the answers to the first question that you linked.**

Comment: Remember; Eval === Evil

Comment: This is not the best way, just use the array, however: `$$key = sanitize($value);` would be better.

Comment: Is this for a test or for some code you are writing? Because there is a more elegant solution to your problem which additionally can help you with the dangers or hidden bugs this can create.

Comment: `===` compare value and its data type.

Comment: Why not use `filter_input_array()` or similar.  No need for `eval()` here at all.

Comment: if `$key = 'removeFile';`, `strstr` will return `0` (because the position of the matched needle is `0`, and you'll end up `eval`-ing what you don't want => do type and value checks: `=== false`, but better still would be not to use `eval` at all. Heck, even _variable variables_ would be better: `$$key = sanitize($value);`

Comment: sjagr user I use `"\$"` backslash but didn't work.

Comment: This is a wonderful example of [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). There are many ways to tackle your problem. This is not the way to do it. The way to do it is to explain what you want to achieve. Not HOW you want to achieve it.

Answer (score 2):

First, the issues I have with your code:

1. `eval` is very, very rarely needed, and extremely dangerous, use with caution. I've been developing in PHP for over 10 years, and never *really* encountered a situation that needed `eval`. This is no exception. Eval is not required
2. You're sanitizing the entire `$_POST` array. That's great, but there are special functions for doing that, like: [`filter_input_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php), [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and many, many more... not to mention ready-made, open source projects and frameworks that already contain a solid request validation component.
3. Always check the return values of functions, which you seem to be doing with `strstr`, but be weary of functions that return different types (like `strstr`: it returns `false` if the needle isn't found, but returns `0` if the needle is found at the start of the haystack string). Your `if` statement might not work as intended.
4. You're assuming `sanitize($value)` values will not contain any single quotes. Why? Because if they do, you'll end up with a syntax error in your evaled string

Be that as it may, you could easily write your code using *variable variables* ***and*** add a simple check not to step on existing variables in scope:

```
$sanitized = array_filter($_POST, 'sanitize');//call sanitize on all values
foreach ($sanitized as $key => $value)
{
    if (!isset($$key) && strstr($key, 'removeFile') === false)
        $$key = $value;
}
```

But really, `$_POST` values belong together, they are part of the request, and should remain grouped... either in an array, or in an object of some sort. Don't assign each value to its own variable, because pretty soon you'll loose track of what variables are set and which are not. Using an unset variable creates that variable, assigning value `null`, so what you have now makes for ***very*** error-prone code:

```
//request 1: POST => id=123&foo=bar
foreach ($sanitized as $k => $v)
    $$k = $v;
$query = 'SELECT x, y, z FROM tbl WHERE id = ?';//using posted ID as value
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array($id));
```

All is well, because `$id` was set, but *never trust the network*, don't assume that, just because `$_POST` is set, all the keys will be set, and their values will be correct:

```
//request 2: POST => foo=bar&page=2
foreach ($sanitized as $k => $v)
    $$k = $v;
$query = 'SELECT x, y, z FROM tbl WHERE id = ?';//using posted ID as value
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array($id));//id is null
```

Now we have a problem. This is just *one* example of how your code might cause issues. Imagine the script grows a bit, and look at this:

```
//request 3: POST => id=123&foo=bar&page=2
foreach ($sanitized as $k => $v)
    $$k = $v;
//$id is 123, $foo is bar and $page = 2
$query = 'SELECT x, y, z FROM tbl WHERE id = ? LIMIT 10';//using posted ID as value
//a lot more code containing this statement:
$page = someFunc();
$log->write('someFunc returned log: '.$page);
//more code
$offset = 10*($page-1);//<-- page is not what we expected it to be
$query .= sprintf(' OFFSET %d', $offset);
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array($id));
```

Now this may seem far-fetched, and idiotic, but believe me: all of these things **happen**, more than I care to know. Adding some code that accidentally overwrites an existing variable that is used further down happens all the time. Especially in procedural code. Don't just blindly unpack an array. Keep that single variable, and use the keys to avoid:

- grey hair
- sudden, dramatic baldness
- loss of sanity
- bleeding ulcers
- In a work environment: catastrophic loss of data
- Sudden loss of job
- ... because code like this makes unicorns cry, and *bronies* will hunt you down

Comment: @user3833682: please consider accepting this answer. To do so, click the tick mark to the left of the answer, so it turns green. This is how we mark questions as resolved here, and it rewards the helper a little bit for their effort too.

Answer (score 1):

As the first answer to the post you linked to, the problem is that when using double quotes PHP thinks your `eval()` code starts with a variable. As that is not the case you have two options. Use single quotes and remember to escape the single quotes declaring a string in the code or escape the dollar sign.

**Bonus note**

There exist more elegant solutions to the problem you are trying to solve. The best solution I can think of is using the [`extract`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function. This gives to two main benefits.

1. It works with all associative arrays
2. You can specify different flags that can help you distinguish the extracted variables apart and avoid variable injection.

One flag you can use is `EXTR_PREFIX_ALL`. This will prefix all the extracted variables with your own prefix. You would then access the variables with a prefix of 'PREFIX_' like the following:

```
$array = [
    'variable1' => 'foo', 
    'variable2' => 'bar' 
];

extract($array, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'PREFIX_');

$value1 = $PREFIX_variable1; // Equals: foo
$value2 = $PREFIX_variable2; // Equals: bar
```

**A little on code injection**

Suppose you have some code:

```
$login = false;
```

The `$login` variable determines if a user is logged in or not.
Then somewhere you use the ´extract´ function with an array of the following without using any flags.

```
$array = [
    'login' => true,
    'foo'   => 'bar'
];

extract($array);
```

Now your `$login` variable would be set to `true` and the user posting the data would have overwritten the initial setting and gained access to your website without a valid login. Bear in mind this is a over simplified example, but nonetheless valid.

To overcome this you can use the flag `EXTR_SKIP` or prefix them like I previously showed. The `EXTR_SKIP` flag will skip the array element if a variable with the same name already is defined. So now your code would not overwrite your `$login` variable.

```
extract($array, EXTR_SKIP); // Skip existing variables
// Or
extract($array, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'prefix'); // Prefix them all.
```

Hope this can guide to the right choice for your needs.

Regards.